# JpaRepository saves more than one entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

tnxRepository is extending JpaRepository, why both entities are getting saved when I am only saving one? CrudRepository only saves the target one.

```java
Tnx tnx = tnxRepository.findById(id);
tnx.txt = txt;
Tnx tnx2 = tnxRepository.findById(2);
tnx2.txt = txt;
tnxRepository.save(tnx);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JpaRepository ties your repositories to JPA persistence technology, hence on save(), both the objects get persisted. Also, JpaRepository extends CrudRepository, so it provides all the functionalities offered by CrudRepository and more.

CrudRepository is a base interface that provides CRUD operations. Hence, not all the objects get persisted,but only the one you saved.

Comment: save method inherited from CrudRepository , the behavior should be equal.

Comment: Way of implementing it in JpaRepository changes as there are other interfaces implemented by JpaRepository other than CrudRepository like PagingAndRepository and Repository. That's the magic of OOPS!

Answer (score 2):

Because for persistent entities hibernate automatically detect change of it and update the database. Even if you don't save last one both entity will updated.

Comment: I can understand all entities will be updated, but JpaRepository inherit save method from CurdRepository, and their behavior is different, so weird.

Comment: They all come from SimpleJPARepository and call entityManager in the end. Like @eklavya said,  you don't need `tnxRepository.save` if you have `@Transactional` annotation because every object that was fetched in the transaction is being tracked by hibernate for any updates

Answer (score 0):

See [saveAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-) method.

eg.

```java
Tnx tnx = tnxRepository.findById(id);
tnx.txt = txt;
Tnx tnx2 = tnxRepository.findById(2);
tnx2.txt = txt;
tnxRepository.saveAll(List.of(tnx, tnx2))
```